# Local and Heroku migrations out of sync

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

It all started when I tried cloning my heroku database to local for good data to test with. When I did the clone and ran `foreman start` I got an error when I opened the page saying that a migration was neccessary. Running `rake db:migrate` said that tables were already created, so I tried migrating on Heroku (I'm a first time Heroku user, so I thought this happened automatically) I got the same error.

Essentially what it comes down to, my app works in Heroku, but the migrations appear to still be pending. So I'm unable to clone my data, but everything still works when I visit my herokuapp.com link.

LOCAL: `rake db:migrate:status`

```
 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20150413052713  Create users
   up     20150413053126  Create posts
   up     20150413053529  Create comments
```

LOCAL: `rake db:version`

```
Current version: 20150413053529
```

HEROKU: `heroku run rake db:migrate:status`

```
Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20150329084143  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150405203900  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150405204241  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150405205232  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150405222631  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150405222654  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150405233628  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150406052414  ********** NO FILE **********
  down    20150413052713  Create users
  down    20150413053126  Create posts
  down    20150413053529  Create comments
```

HEROKU: `heroku run rake db:version`

```
Current version: 20150406052414
```

I can't reset my heroku database because that's my production database.